# Skip values if not present in ANTLR4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I have a file which I want to parse and in that file, there are values dependent on other values. for example, consider this file

0,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,9,7,2,1,2

here 4 states that the next 4 numbers are a sequence of 4 numbers. if it is 2 then there will be only 2 numbers. same goes for the 2 which is in 3rd place from the last it states that there are 2 numbers. How to write a grammar that skips the fields if there are not present in cases like this considering there is a max limit like 8 or 10 for this sequence.

and another case is depending upon a value there are some fields that are present or not for example

1, 2, 3, 52, 5, 8, 6, 9 here consider 52 states that 8 is present and 6 is not so the series will be 1, 2, 3, 52, 5, 8, 9 then how to skip this field and parse the others. thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO you should not try to add such semantic checks to the parser. The parser should just parse a comma separated list of values and then after the parse tree is created, you validate it in a listener or visitor.

Comment: Yes I know that but the thing is these comma separated values change all the time, there is a max limit on how many fields there will be and I want separate methods created for these fields when I generate classes from this grammar. For that reason, I'm trying to separate these fields. Is there any way on how to stop the rule at a specific point, I have written a grammar that parses this type of data but I couldn't figure out how to stop it from parsing other values that don't belong to these fields.

Answer (score 0):

I tried validating input during parsing before as well and let me tell you this: It is a total mess and will most likely not work properly.
This is due to the fact that a parser should do exactly that: parse the input. All validations that need to be performed on the parsed data should be performed within a Listener or a Visitor and thus after having parsed the file.

Therefore I strongly advice you to follow @Bart Kiers's advice from the comments and just parse the whole thing as a comma-separated list and do all context-sensitive validation and grouping after parsing.

EDIT:
You stated that you need to have separate (visit)-methods for all sub-sequences found in the CSV. That can be achieved by a custom walker- + listener-system build on top of your grouping-algorithm. Therefore you'd go ahead and parse the file, then group all sub-sequences together and create some sort of data structure out of it. Then you'd take that structure and feed it into your custom walker that in turn notifies custom listeners about certain encountered sub-sequences.